# Spring mvc @RequestBody String format

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one Controller : personController.java

```
@Controller 
public class personController {     

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OcaController.class);  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})        
    public String ocaContract(@RequestBody String requestPerson) {
        return requestPerson;
    }
```

1 JSP : person.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" METHOD="POST" ACTION="webmvc/person" ENCTYPE="x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and one Object Class : Person.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class Person {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String surname;

 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
} ...
```

When I populate the JSP and click on the input button, my controller return this "requestPerson" string :

```
name=&surname=
```

Is it a way to have this string as a POJO ? My final result must be at the XML format :

```
<person>
<name>Lisala</name>
<surname>Lili</surname></person>
```

I hope you ll can help me because i'm on it since 1 day now and i didn't find an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: This is nullable= true a typo in :@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)

Comment: xjc generate this code... I think it doesn't matter

Comment: So your question is how to replace `String` with `Person`?

Comment: Yes but I have Error HTTP 415 - when I try to replace String by Person...

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `@RequestBody` with `@ModelAttribute` and `String` to `Person`

`public String ocaContract(@ModelAttribute Person requestPerson) {`